# How to install VimClojure on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, clojure, vimclojure

I would appreciate a pointer to instructions on how to install VimClojure on a Windows 7 workstation. I have lein and everything it needs installed and working.

My files are located in my default login directory under c:\Users\

```
  .lein

  .m2

  vimfiles

0 _gvimrc

4 _viminfo

6 _vimrc
```

Where should VimClojure be located? For now, I've put it under `vimfiles`. Is that correct? I am not interested in using NailGun at the moment. I just want the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. `vimfiles` should be correct. You can also check in a running vim for `:set rtp?` (note trailing question mark). This should give the path, where vim is looking for scripts.